# Microsoft Excel - "help function" to output values to an alternative cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to use specific Microsoft Excel cells (without using VB) as "help function" to output values to an alternative cell?

For example:

Cell A1 has the value 10.
Cell C1 has the value 10.

Cell B1 contains the following formula:
=IF(A1=C1;B4="Hooray!";B4="Oh no!")
and outputs "WRONG" :-(

Does anyone of you guys have any idea(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the output of an `IF` statement in one cell to directly set the output of another cell.

Your formula says to Excel, if `A1=C1`, then check if `B4="Hooray!"` and tell me if that's true or false. But if A1 does not equal C1, then check if `B4="Oh no!"` and tell me if that's true or false. That's why you're getting `WRONG` (or `FALSE` on my machine) - because cell B4 does not equal **Hooray!** or **Oh no!**.

What you could do is put the following formula **in cell B4** (not B1).

```
=IF(A1=C1;"Hooray!";"Oh no!")
```